# How to find an approximate values of rational function $f(x)$ for large $x$, neglecting $\frac{1}{x^4}$ and successive terms?

Tags: calculus, asymptotics, rational-functions

This is the function that I want to find an approximate value for it neglecting $\displaystyle \frac{1}{x^4}$ and successive terms

$$
f(x)=\frac{25x}{(x-2)^2(x^2+1)}.
$$

Comment: Use Taylor expansion around the wanted value.
Or what is the expression of $\frac1{x-2}$ and of $\frac1{x^2+1}$? From this you could deduce the approximate value up to $\frac1{x^4}$

Answer (score 3):

Write this with $t= 1/x$, to get:
$$f(x)=\frac{25x}{(x-2)^2(x^2+1)}\to\frac{25 t^3}{(1-2 t)^2 \left(t^2+1\right)}= 25 t^3\cdot\frac{1}{(1-2 t)^2 \left(t^2+1\right)}$$
Now expand the fraction as a Taylor series to first order, to get:
$$25t^3(1+4t)+O(t^5)$$
Or, back to $x$:
$$\frac{25}{x^3}+\frac{100}{x^4}+O(x^{-5})$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $\frac1{1+x}=1+O(x)$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{25x}{(x-2)^2(x^2+1)}
&=\frac{25}{x^3(1-\frac2x)^2(1+\frac1{x^2})}\\[9pt]
&=\frac{25}{x^3}\left(1+O\left(\frac1x\right)\right)^2\left(1+O\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)\right)\\[6pt]
&=\frac{25}{x^3}\left(1+O\left(\frac1x\right)\right)\\[6pt]
&=\frac{25}{x^3}+O\left(\frac1{x^4}\right)
\end{align}
$$